# Convert two 1D arrays into single 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 1d arrays and i am trying to populate them into a single 2d array in JAVA.

For instance:

```
a[] = {2,7} 
b[] = {9,1}
```

The results should then be:

```
result[][] = {{2,9}, {7,1}}
```

This is my code

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Test Cases:\t");
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    int[] a;
    int[] b;
    int i, j, x;
    for (int k = 0; k < t; k++) {
        System.out.println("Enter 1st Array Limit:\t");
        int len = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter 2nd Array Limit:\t");
        int len1 = sc.nextInt();
        a = new int[len];
        b = new int[len1];
        System.out.println("Enter Sum Value");
        x = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter " + len + " elements:\t");
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter " + len1 + " elements:\t");
        for (j = 0; j < len1; j++) {
            b[j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int [][] c = new int[len][2];
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < len1; j++) {
                if (a[i] + b[j] == x) {
                    for(int l = 0; i < a.length; i++){
                        c[l][0] = a[i];
                        c[l][1] = b[j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(c));
    }
}
}
```

This still produces wrong output

i want to find Find all pairs with a given sum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int[] a = {2,7};
int[] b = {9,1};
int[][] c = new int[a.length][2];
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    c[i][0] = a[i];
    c[i][1] = b[i];
}
```

should do the trick

Comment: Followed your suggestion still not getting the right output

Comment: Try to copy and paste this code, and run it (tell me what it outputs):  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] a = {2,7};
  int[] b = {9,1};
  int[][] c = new int[a.length][2];
  for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
   c[i][0] = a[i];
   c[i][1] = b[i];
  }
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(c));
 }

Comment: [[2, 9], [7, 1]]

Comment: Isnt that the desired output?

Comment: I am trying to get this condition true then insert those two elements into the array    a[i]+b[j]==sum then insert into c[][];

Comment: Yes that the desired output